# Numerical values in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I apologize if this is a duplicate and I realize this is rather broad. I'm having a bit of trouble trying to understand how I would approach the following:

I want to define a numerical value and allow the user to click checkboxes say for a number of sides and the corresponding sides. Now after each successive side clicked the value (number of sides) would decrease and display the updated amount in the webpage.

How would I go about this! Define all the variables etc in jquery then create functions to check if the checkboxes have been clicked then decrease the variable by updating it.
However after this how would I actually use this variable in the html portion(s) to display the number of sides remaining? As I understand it html doesn't really have variables. Sorry if this was confusing I'm new to web programming

Comment: `jQuery('#output').html(numberremaining)`? Where `#output` is an HTML element with id `output` and `numberremaining` is your JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you will not be able to do this in HTML alone, you can use jQuery to define a variable which would be the total number of sides a user could select and then decrease that variable each time a checkbox is clicked(or increase if they deselect it).

Here's a simple example to get you started, you could also expand on this to prevent the user from being able to check any more boxes if they've chosen the limited number of sides.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sidesRemaining = 3;
    $('.sidesRemaining').html(sidesRemaining);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           // Decrease total by 1
           sidesRemaining -= 1;
       } else {
           // Increase total by 1
           sidesRemaining += 1;
       }
       $('.sidesRemaining').html(sidesRemaining);
    });
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88vz28c9/1/)

Comment: Thank you this worked. However, unless I misunderstand how this works this will always increment or decrease the counter when a checkbox is clicked, but what if there are other checkboxes in other divs?

Comment: Then you would need to make the jQuery selector more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* store data in the web page by storing it as a string in an attribute, or within an element.

In many cases, though, it is better to just keep hold of the variables in JavaScript, where they will return their type.

```
var x = 5;

document.getElementById('example').setAttribute('data-var-x', x);

var y = document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('data-var-x');
```

In the above example, using `x` means you have the number `5`, whereas using `y` means you have the string `"5"`. You would need to parse it into a number to use it properly... for example using this [slacker parsing](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201402/Blog/Slacker-Parsing-In-JavaScript/):

```
var y = +document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('data-var-x');
```

Or you can use `parseInt` (boring!)

```
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('data-var-x'), 10);
```